# Unable to load sqljdbc_auth.dll for jdbc sql server'08 connection

Tags: java, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 using sqljdbc4.jar in Eclipse IDE. And I am giving the dll path in Run configurations as in VM arguments as –Djava.libary.path="C: /Users/rrpall/workspace/AnnouncmentsFilter/sqljdbc_auth"

I am running my program from junit test case and I am geting the following error:

My junit test case

```
package org.nsp.announcmentsfilter.test;

import org.nsp.announcmentsfilter.dao.SqlConnection;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class SqlConnectionTest extends TestCase 
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection;

    public void setUp()
    {
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
    }

    public void testConnection()
    {
        sqlConnection.getSqlConnection();
        sqlConnection.setQuery("SELECT NAME FROM NSP_CONTENT_C WHERE FLEXTEMPLATEID = '1293724126089'");

    }

}


Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: –Djava/libary/path=C: /Users/rrpall/workspace/AnnouncmentsFilter/sqljdbc_auth
Caused by: Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: –Djava.libary.path=C: .Users.rrpall.workspace.AnnouncmentsFilter.sqljdbc_auth
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

And a pop-up window saying "
could not find the main class: "Djava.library.path = C: /Users/rrpall/workspace/AnnouncmentsFilter/sqljdbc_auth. program will exit"

My original code is

```
package org.nsp.announcmentsfilter.dao;

import Java.sql.*;

public class SqlConnection  
{
     String driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
     String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://KWIDBSQLD02:10432;integratedSecurity=true";
     String dbUser="root";
     String dbPwd= "";
     Connection conn = null;
    public void getSqlConnection()
    {
        try 
        {
            Class.forName(driverClassName);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        }

        catch (Exception e) 
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public ResultSet setQuery(String query)
    {
        Statement statement;
        try 
        {
            statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
            return resultSet; 
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: sounds like you might be putting the VM arguments in the wrong option. Can you post a screenshot of the Eclipse run config?

Comment: its not letting me to upload the picture i already tried